# issue in setting image of navigation bar while presentModalViewController

Tags: ios, navigationbar

this is how i set image in my first class in viewDidLoad which is tableView

```
  if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }

now this how i go to detail view

 DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

in detail view's bar the image which i have set for navigation bar comes automatically there and everything works perfect

now my problem is that pushViewController is working perfectly images are getting displayed 
but i get default image in presentModelViewController this is how i use it

```
- (void) modelappear
{

    if (self.testModalViewController == nil) 
    {
        TestModalViewController *temp = [[TestModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestModalViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.testModalViewController = temp;
        [temp release];
    }

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.testModalViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
}
```

Note i just set buttons in inner hierarchy views

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong? please give explanation with answer thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
    UIImageView *imageViewe = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


    UILabel *tmpTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 3, 150, 40)];
    [tmpTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];


    tmpTitleLabel.text = @"Add Manually";

    tmpTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    tmpTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    CGRect applicationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);
    UIView * newView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame] autorelease];
    [newView addSubview:imageViewe];
    [newView addSubview:tmpTitleLabel];


    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:newView];
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
     DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     dvController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIIMage imageNamed:@"name.png"]];
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Comment: there is no problem in pushViewController Problem is in PresentViewConroller  how to solve that ?

Comment: this is not working brother it works only with PushViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: one should do this in viewwillapper not in viewdidload